# VB6 code translation Date1 > (Date2 + 30)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to translate this VB6 code to VB.NET
but I cannot seem to understand how does this code adds 30 to a Date?

Code:

```
if Date1 > (Date2 + 30) then
'Condition
end if
```

**Question:**

1. What value of the 2 date does the code calculates? (Is it `day > day`, `month > month` ,`year > year`?)
2. Where does the value **30** adds? (`Day`, `month` or `year`?)
3. What is the equivalent of this **VB6** code to **VB.NET**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It determines if the date in `Date1` is greater than the date in `Date2` plus 30 days.
2. It adds days
3. You would call `dateVar.AddDays()`

Comment: Am I doing it right? `If Date1.Value.Date > DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 30, Date2.Value.Date)`

Comment: or like this `If Date1.Value.Date > Date2.Value.Date.AddDays(30)`

Answer (score 3):

In `VB6` / `VBA`, you can add an integer to a date variable and it would add that many days to it.
So, `Date2 + 30` is same as `DateAdd("D", 30, Date2)`

In VB.NET, `Date+Integer` is not supported. So you must resort to the 2nd way to add days to a date.

So the equivalent of your code in VB.NET would be:

```
If date1 > date2.AddDays(30) Then
    'Condition
End If
```

The `DateAdd("D", 30, Date2)` syntax is still supported (though I won't recommend using it). So the following would work too:

```
If date1 > DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 30, date2) Then
    'Condition
End If
```